SQL - Update column with earliest date from another column
table name: transcript



transcriptid
userid
moduleid
linkid
type
startdate




t1
user1
p1
p1
program
1970-01-01 01:00:00.000


t2
user1
m1
p1
module
2024-05-03 12:34:19.777


t3
user1
m2
p1
module
2024-05-03 13:05:52.630






transcriptid
userid
moduleid
linkid
type
startdate




t4
user2
p2
p2
program
1970-01-01 01:00:00.000


t5
user2
m3
p2
module
2024-04-03 08:34:19.777


t6
user2
m4
p2
module
2024-04-03 10:05:52.630



Context:
I have a program module (p1) that contains 2 submodules (m1,m2).
The issue is that program modules startdate aren't updating correctly for several programs and they should match the startdate of the earliest submodule that was started (e.g. t2)
The linkid column uses the moduleid to link submodules to the program module (e.g. m1,m2 are submodules of p1)
What im wating to do is update the startdate for program modules to use the earliest startdate from the linked submodules.
transcriptid t1 should be using the startdate from t2.
transcriptid t4 should be using the startdate from t5.
Hope that all makes sense!
